# Binary data serialization/deserialization between api and browser

Tags: javascript, rest, http, browser, server

I have attempted to send data from the server to a react client using both https://cbor.io/ and https://msgpack.org/ and I keep getting errors in chunk.js when using either of them. With msgpack the error is

```
Unhandled Rejection (RangeError): Extra 74440 byte(s) found at buffer[1]
```

With cbor the error is

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Invalid non-string/buffer chunk
```

If I request the same data using a client running on the server decoding the data works just fine using either format.

I haven't ever really attempted to use a data format other than json or plain text when communicating between a browser client and the server, so I am wondering if there is something I am not aware of I need to do make this work?

I am not sure if the issue is data corruption between the server and the client, if I need to set some special header fields in the request/response, if compression needs to used, or what. Really lost as to what the issue is or may be.

[edit]
Here is an example of the server code

```
import Koa, {Middleware} from 'koa'
import bodyParser from 'koa-bodyparser'
import Router from '@koa/router'
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as util from 'util'
import cborParser from 'koa-cbor-bodyparser'
import koaQs from 'koa-qs'
import koaHelmet from 'koa-helmet'
import { encodeAsync} from 'cbor'
import cors from '@koa/cors'
const app = koaQs(new Koa())
const defaultMiddleware = [bodyParser(), cborParser(), koaHelmet(), cors()]
const useMiddleware = (middleware?: Middleware<Koa.ParameterizedContext>[]) => defaultMiddleware.forEach(mddlwr => app.use(mddlwr))

const rt = new Router()

const read = async (file: string) => {
    const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)
    return readFile(file)
}

rt.get('/image', async ctx => {
    const data = await read('/home/beckspoppn/Dev/trykoa/image.jpg')
    const resp = {name: 'gary', data, age: 37}
    const body = await encodeAsync(resp)
    console.log(body)
    ctx.status = 200
    ctx.body = body
    ctx.response.type = 'application/cbor'
})

useMiddleware()
app.use(rt.routes())
app.listen(3000)
```

and here is the client

```
import React from 'react'
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import {decodeAll} from 'cbor'

const getImage = async () => {
    //
    console.log('performing request')
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/image', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
    console.log(response.data)

    const [data] = await decodeAll(response.data)
    console.log(data)
    return data
}

const onClick = async () => {
    await getImage()

  }
function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <button onClick={onClick}></button>
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The code using msgpack is more or less the exact same except to for the encoding/decoding is changed to match that library.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Needs example code: How do you parse/receive the data from the server on the client?

Comment: @scootermefecit I added examples. Thanks.

Comment: What does the console.log() statement output? Anything useful or insightful? (No, you don't need to edit and post everything from console.log()'s output, naturally, but what does it tell you?)

Comment: @scootermefecit On the server it logs the encoded data. On the client it says ArrayBuffer byteLength: 7262